# Create a git worktree from a bare repo without a remote path?

Tags: git

I'm attempting to create a bare repo, and then 'git worktree add' from it to a worktree. But this errors out consistently.  Please see the repro of what I'm seeing, immediately below.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eux
set -o pipefail

# I'm using git version 2.30.2 in a Debian 11.2 docker container.

branch_name=foo
bare_repo_dir=$(set -eu; mktemp --directory /tmp/bare_repo-XXXXXXXX)
worktree_dir=$(set -eu; mktemp --directory /tmp/worktree-XXXXXXXX)
# shellcheck disable=SC2064
trap "rm -rf \"$bare_repo_dir\" \"$worktree_dir\"" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
git init --bare "$bare_repo_dir"
cd "$bare_repo_dir"

git config --global init.defaultBranch master

# This errors out with:
#     Preparing worktree (new branch 'foo')
#     fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.
git worktree add --no-checkout -b "$branch_name" "$worktree_dir/$branch_name" master
```

Comment: @phd It has neither, because I just created the repo.  "git checkout -b master" doesn't help.  If I "git branch -a", I get no output.

Comment: You cannot do `git checkout` in a bare repo — the command requires a working tree. Well, that's a fresh empty bare repo so there is no a branch in it. [`git worktree add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#Documentation/git-worktree.txt-addltpathgtltcommit-ishgt) has `--force` option, may be it could help.

Comment: There ought to exist an option, probably spelled `--orphan`, for `git worktree add` that would let you do what you want. There isn't, but there might be soon; see VonC's comment in the duplicate.